# Searching a dataset for face recognition

Tags: database, computer-vision, dataset, face-recognition, facial-identification

I'm working on facial recognition project.
can anyone give me a dataset for facial recognition?

find a dataset of faces for facial recognition images and/or videos

Comment: Be more specific about requirements, there are various kind of facial recognition datasets, try kaggle datasets

Comment: i just need only human faces dataset

Comment: https://analyticsindiamag.com/10-face-datasets-to-start-facial-recognition-projects/

Comment: http://vintage.winklerbros.net/facescrub.html

Comment: https://ibug.doc.ic.ac.uk/resources/facial-point-annotations/